# ADODB Command.Execute Timeout

Tags: excel, sql-server-2012, adodb, vba

I am seeing a timeout error when running a query from Excel vba

The query takes <2 seconds from the SQL Server Management Studio, but from vba the timeout happens at 2 minutes with nothing returned

Is there something i am not doing right setting up the Command object? I have noticed that ADODB seems to be slower but never anything like this

The query joins several tables and does some other calculations, but going from 1.5 seconds to >2 minutes must mean something in the vba that I have missed

This is my vba connection string code:

```
If svrCon Is Nothing Then
    Set svrCon = New ADODB.Connection
End If

If Not CheckServerConnectionState Then

    conStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ussantapps332;" & _
                    "Initial Catalog=Global_OEE_Data_Capture_Dev;User Id=sqluser;Password=*****;"

    ' Open the connection
    svrCon.ConnectionTimeout = 0
    svrCon.Open conStr

End If
```

This is my vba SELECT code:

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim par As ADODB.Parameter
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset        

' Create command object
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
cmd.ActiveConnection = svrCon
cmd.CommandText = sql


' Create parameter object
If IsArrayInitialized(params) Then
    For x = 0 To UBound(params)
        If IsNull(params(x, 1)) Then
            Set par = cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=params(x, 0), Size:=1)
        Else
            Set par = cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=params(x, 0), Size:=Len(params(x, 1)) + 1)
        End If
        par.Value = params(x, 1)

        cmd.Parameters.Append par

        Set par = Nothing

        DoEvents
    Next
End If


' Open recordset object
On Error GoTo ExecuteError
Debug.Print Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
Set rst = cmd.Execute
Debug.Print Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
On Error GoTo 0
```

The sql string and parameters are passed into the function, the connection is opened from another method

The query is:

```
SELECT U.UnitsID, L.LineName, V.VSName, O.OperatorShift, O.LineLeader, O.CotyOps, O.TempOps, U.WorkOrder, U.ProductCode,
           S.ProdDesc, U.TimeLineStart, U.TimeLineEnd, U.UnitsProduced, U.ActLineSpeed, U.TgtLineSpeed, SUM(CASE WHEN C.DTIncludedInOEE = 0 THEN D.DowntimeLength ELSE 0 END),
           U.OfflineTaskID, R.Rate, S.LabHrsPerThou, S.PHeads, T.TgtOEE, T.TgtEff, T.TgtProd
      FROM dataUnits U
        LEFT JOIN dataOperatorNames O ON O.OperatorID = U.OperatorNameID
        INNER JOIN setupLines L ON U.LineID = L.LineID
        INNER JOIN setupValueStreams V on V.VSID = L.VSID
        INNER JOIN setupPUs P ON V.PUID = P.PUID
        LEFT JOIN dataDowntimes D ON U.UnitsID = D.UnitsID
        LEFT JOIN setupDowntimes sD ON D.DTID = sD.DTID
        LEFT JOIN setupDowntimeCats C ON sD.DTCatID = C.DTCatID
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT VSID, AVG(RateVal) Rate
                 FROM dataRates WHERE FYStart >= '2014-07-01' AND FYStart < '2015-07-01'
                        GROUP BY VSID) R ON R.VSID = L.VSID
        LEFT JOIN dataStandards S ON S.ProdCode = U.ProductCode
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT LineID, AVG(TgtOEE) TgtOEE, AVG(TgtEff) TgtEff, AVG(TgtProd) TgtProd
                    FROM dataTargets WHERE TgtMonth >= '2015-03-01' AND TgtMonth < '2015-04-01'
                            GROUP BY LineID) T ON L.LineID = T.LineID
      WHERE (S.SAPVersion = (SELECT MIN(SAPVersion) FROM dataStandards s2 WHERE s2.ProdCode = S.ProdCode)
            OR S.SAPVersion IS NULL)
      AND P.SiteID = 2 AND U.TimeLineStart >= '2015-03-05 23:00' AND U.TimeLineStart < '2015-03-31 23:00'
      GROUP BY U.UnitsID, L.LineName, V.VSName, O.OperatorShift, O.LineLeader, O.CotyOps, O.TempOps, U.WorkOrder, U.ProductCode, S.ProdDesc, U.TimeLineStart,
               U.TimeLineEnd, U.UnitsProduced, U.ActLineSpeed, U.TgtLineSpeed, U.OfflineTaskID, R.Rate, S.LabHrsPerThou, S.PHeads, T.TgtOEE, T.TgtEff, T.TgtProd
      ORDER BY U.TimeLineStart ASC
```

Comment: Is my understanding correct that queries run from SQL Server Management Studio and from Excel VBA have the same input parameters and are run against the same database?

Comment: yes the query is the same, i used the same parameters and the database is the same

Comment: Did you try to run this query in Excel VBA two times one by one. I'd like to confirm that it always takes 2 minutes to execute it and not only for the first time.

Comment: It takes longer then 2 mins, i have set that as the timeout and it errors each time. I am changing the timeout to zero to see how long it takes, i will run it a couple of times and get back to you

Comment: so 3 runs - 1st took 2min 31, 2nd took 2min 27, 3rd took 2min 35

Comment: What is your connection string? What library do you use in Excel (e.g. Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74239/discussion-between-michal-komorowski-and-iabbott).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discussion on the chat showed that:

- The problem occurs only while connecting to the remote database.
- The old SQLOLEDB provider is used.

I suggested to give a chance to a newer provider SQLNCLI which should be more effective while communicating with MSSQL. When a connection string was modified the execution time dropped from 2 minutes to 3 seconds.

Comment: So finally my connection string looks like: `conStr = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source= (......).`